# Correct Method of Prefilling data()

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js

I'm creating a Vue.js component that will serve a form on my site.

I want this form component to be used for both create, and edit.

For this, I rely on loading a prop `project` with a `project` object. The presence, or absence of this object, on load, will tell me if it's an edit form, or a create form, respectively.

The problem is, if I want to use this as an edit form, then I want the form data to be prefilled. To do this, I'm left with these ugly ternary operators that check for the property, and if it's present, fill the key.

```
data() {
    return {
        form: {
            id: (this.project ? this.project.id : ''),
            name: (this.project ? this.project.name : ''),
            description: (this.project ? this.project.description : ''),
        }
    };
},
```

I'm still fairly new to Vue.js and I'm trying to grasp the correct way to do things. This method feels wrong, and so I'm pretty sure there's a better way. Can you help me out?

My goal is to prefill the form on edit mode, and have the form filled with empty values if it's in create mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same approach I would use, however I would avoid nesting it in an object you need to test for and the ternary operators and simplify it with:

```
    form: {
        id: this.id || '',
        name: this.name || '',
        description: this.description || ''),
    }
```

The approach you're using with the `project` object isn't something I've seen. From what I've seen, I think it's more common in Vue.js to deal with complexity through components.

[This repo](https://github.com/SNiels/gkeep-vueifire) (and the accompanying tutorial) has a good example of this, with the [Note component](https://github.com/SNiels/gkeep-vueifire/tree/master/src/components/notes) Create.vue having the data and Index.vue applying rules when the form is presented.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to initialize the data of component:

```
template: `
  <div>
    id: <input type="text" v-model="project.id" number>
    name: <input type="text" v-model="project.name">
    description: <input type="text" v-model="project.description">
  </div>
`,
props: {
  project: {
    type: Object,
    default: {}
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pespantelis/1L9adm32/2/